# Codeigniter reroute if language parameter not set

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes

So using this library: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CodeIgniter_2.1_internationalization_i18n, I am wondering why if I access to `http://test.com/home` it redirects to `http://test.com/en/home`, but if I try accessing `http://test.com/video/123asd` it doesn't redirect to `http://test.com/en/video/123asd`.

Any ideas why could that be happening?

This is my `routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";

// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|es|ro)/video/(.+)$']  = "fetch/video/$2";
$route['^(en|es|ro)/results$']     = "fetch/results$2";
$route['^(en|es|ro)/(.+)$']        = "$2";

// '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|es|ro)$'] = $route['default_controller'];

$route['404_override']  = '';
```

Comment: "This" library? Which library?

Comment: sorry, I edited the post and added a link to the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI routing doesn't handle URL redirection; they specify URL relationships to controllers and methods.

For redirects, add a `redirect()`, preferably in your controller, or use .htaccess if you're on an Apache server.

Comment: yea, but I was wondering why for home redirects and for the other controllers doesn't